# Sqitch deploy to snowflake DW fails

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unixodbc, snowsql, sqitch

The Sqitch deploy command fails with below error:-

```
sqitch deploy 'db:snowflake://amrutmonu:PASSWORD@wea87235.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/DEMO_DB?Driver=Snowflake'
```

error:

> Adding registry tables to db:snowflake://amrutmonu:@wea87235.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/DEMO_DB?Driver=Snowflake
>   250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB. Verify the account name is correct: wea
>   "/root/bin/snowsql" unexpectedly returned exit value 1

Could you please look into this and help us fixing this issue?

Comment: Take a look at this solution
[[snowflake] deploy error](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/issues/420#issuecomment-453199324). It works fine for me. Shortly - you have to add some additional settings in snowsql's config file.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the .snowflakecomputing.com from the connection string, try it out, and let us know how it goes:

```
sqitch deploy 'db:snowflake://amrutmonu:PASSWORD@wea87235.us-east-1/DEMO_DB?Driver=Snowflake'
```

Comment: This time we executed below command - 
sqitch deploy 'db:snowflake://amrutmonu:PASSWORD@wea87235.us-east-1/DEMO_DB?Driver=Snowflake'

But as soon as we hit enter it gives below message -

Adding registry tables to db:snowflake://amrutmonu:@wea87235.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/DEMO_DB?Driver=Snowflake

and after some 50-55 secs below error message appears - 

250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB. Verify the account name is correct: wea
"/root/bin/snowsql" unexpectedly returned exit value 1

Comment: We checked all the configuration from our end.Nothings seems to be wrong.But still if you want to us to check some particular things in configuration please let us know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to access  your snowflake account using below URL: https://wea87235.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com